# How do I change the screen size in cocos2dx v3?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, screen-resolution, cocos2d-x-3.0

I launch my game and it looks like the screen is something like 800x600, but I'm looking for a 1080p screen so that I can test my Nexus 5.

Is there a setting somewhere I can tweak the display resolution of the exe I'm running to test my project?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support?project_id=cocos2d-x), it turned out to be as simple as

```
Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->setFrameSize(1920, 1080);
Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(1920, 1080, ResolutionPolicy::EXACT_FIT);
```

but you need to make sure to call it before any of the `Node`s are initialized or the sizes will be off. Please note that the order in which you call these two functions matter as well.

It seems like your "design resolution" is the internal resolution and "frame size" is the rendered resolution, so if your design resolution is a different aspect ratio, you'll get some stretching.